# WordPress Function.php - Change a character within a page URL when the site is viewed in browser

Tags: wordpress, function, replace, character

I need to get two content pages within WordPress that display the GB '£' symbol to be changed to a US '$' symbol when the site is viewed by a user in a web browser. Not a site wide change, just two specific URLs.

This is content produced with a plugin so I can't simply edit the relevant page.

I need to say in the functions.php:

If page is this URL then find '£' symbol and change to '$' symbol

One important thing is that I'll need to specify this for a number of URLs. Initially just two URLs but I may need to do this again to add a few more URLs.

I found this example to change text in URLs but don't know how to get it to work. E.G. How do you tell it to target specific URLs and also would you need to use ASCII code for the two symbols US $ and GB £:

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('look-for-this-string', 'replace-with-this-string', $text);
    $text = str_replace('look-for-that-string', 'replace-with-that-string', $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

I tried:

```
if ($pageUrl=='http://yoursiteurl.com/page/'){
    $text = str_replace('look-for-this-string', 'replace-with-this-string', $text);
   return $text;
}
```

But know this is not right or structured properly.

Thanks,
Nick.

Comment: Use js ? Add some class or something to the string you want to modify and when its loading the page with js modify string. Also if you cant add class or something to this string body tag holds classes about the post/page/template that you can use to check if the content must be changed

Comment: Thanks. I'm open to using JS rather than functions.php but don't know how to write JS. I've just tested using Better Find and Replace plugin as a different approach. Using plain text as the replacement type works on a test page (a new page with symbol inserted as normal text content). But this has no effect on the instances of £ I want to target. Even if I change the mode of the plugin to use Regular Expression or Ajax. Other options like Custom Expression breaks the site. So this doesn't appear to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to give you 100% working solution. So here is something that will be easy to understand and if you add the correct classes will work.

Add the following code in js file in your theme or load it as new or any other way you can add js. The code must be loaded after jquery is loaded.

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('body.postid-34').length > 0) { // condition if we are on the right page 
        $('.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol').each(function(){ // find all elements with class that we want to change
            $(this).text('€'); // the new currency we want
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```